# TouchableHighlight - Cancelling a long press

Tags: react-native

React native's TouchableHighlight component allows you to listen for a long press.

```
<TouchableHighlight onLongPress={renderOverlay} />
```

Is there any way to then listen for a cancellation of this long press? I had hoped/prayed that if I released the long press over the component it would consider it a press while if I moved my finger off the component and released it would consider it cancelled. All I ever get after onLongPress is onPressOut event though. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

i think TouchableHighlight can't resolve it,
you should use Responder Lifecycle .